# ICS keyboard back,home buttons not taking touch when opened on overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ime

I am creating an Overlay Screen. Everything works perfect on it except the android 4.0+ default keyboard`s back(keyboard down),home & recent apps button when the keyboard is open. These keys do not take the touch and instead the keys above it are being tapped. For example when tapped on back the comma is getting tapped, when tapped home the space key is being tapped etc.

The issue is seen with the android default keyboard from 4.0 onwards only since the samsung devices which have their own keyboard implementation do not show this issue also when in landscape mode the default keyboard works normally but then the keyboard is in full screen mode.

[image]

I am not sure if the fault is in the keyboard implementation or in mine. In anyway the fix should be found since majority users are going to use the default keyboard.

For the Overlay Screen i am using following flags :

```
int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR;

    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    params.flags |= flags;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
```

Please let me know if any more code snippet is required in order to understand my query.I have been through many already asked questions but didn`t found any matching to my query. Hope to find some solution.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error correction introduced in 4.0 IME for touch to key. 
could you check the LatinIME source for same.